# jquery UI datepicker - disabling date ranges

Tags: jquery, user-interface, datepicker, date-range

I'm struggling to get something working - I'm getting a 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined' error with the below and I can't figure out why!

I'm trying to use the jQuery UI datepicker on a site for a holiday cottage to indicate availability and season (low, high etc). I have a function as a datePicker event to check if there's a booking for a date, and if not, I then go out to check which season we're in (In non-peak season bookings can be made on a Monday or Friday. In Peak season, it's Fridays only. )

I'm using a cms to generate some date arrays (via loops) that I can then iterate through when building the calendar, so the javascript is a little verbose.

The arrays look like this:

```
<script> 
//Peak Season 1 2011
var ps1 = new Date('June 17, 2011');
var pe1 = new Date('September 2, 2011');
//Peak Season 2 2011
var ps2 = new Date('December 19, 2011');
var pe2 = new Date('January 6, 2012');
// season start and end date arrays
var peakStart = new Array(ps1,ps2);
var peakEnd = new Array(pe1,pe2);

// Bookings
//Mr &amp; Mrs Smith 
var cbs1 = new Date('May 27, 2011');
var cbe1 = new Date('June 5, 2011');
//Mr &amp; Mrs Jones 
var cbs2 = new Date('September 1, 2011');
var cbe2 = new Date('September 18, 2011');
var cottageStart = new Array(cbs1,cbs2);
var cottageEnd = new Array(cbe1,cbe2);

// last date of season - don't book past here
var lastDate = '01/06/2012';
</script>
```

I have the following function that I call from the beforeShowDate event to check the calendar date against the booking array:

```
$('#cottageCal').datepicker({
    minDate: '0d',
    maxDate: lastDate,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        $.each(cottageStart, function(key, value) { 
          //alert (((date >= value) && (date <= value)) ? 'booked' : 'notbooked');
            if ((date >= value) && (date <= value)) {
                return [false, 'booked'];
            } else {
                return checkPeak(date);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Finally, the checkPeak function that is called from here looks like this:

```
var checkPeak = function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    $.each(peakStart, function(key, value) { 
        if ((date > value) && (date < value)) {
        /* december peak bookings on monday*/
            if (month != 11) {
                return [(day == 5), ''];
            } else {
                return [(day == 1), ''];
            }
        }
        if (month == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            // it's not during a peak period
            return [(day == 1 || day == 5), ''];
        }
    });
}
```

I must be doing something fundamentally wrong here but I can't see what!

Comment: where exactly u r getting error? did u debug the code step by step using `console.log`

Comment: I'm getting 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier' on the line after the beforeShowDay event

Answer (score 10):

Quite an old question, but I got through the same problem, landed here searching for a solution and then resolved by myself paying more attention to the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay):

> beforeShowDay - function(date) The function takes a date as a
>   parameter and **must return an array with [0] equal to true/false
>   indicating whether or not this date is selectable**, [1](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay) equal to a CSS
>   class name(s) or '' for the default presentation, and [2] an optional
>   popup tooltip for this date. It is called for each day in the
>   datepicker before it is displayed.

So, just to be sure, I would rewrite the orginal question's code explicitely like this:

```
$('#cottageCal').datepicker({
    minDate: '0d',
    maxDate: lastDate,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        $.each(cottageStart, function(key, value) { 
            if ((date >= value) && (date <= value)) {
                return new Array(false, 'booked');
            } else {
                return checkPeak(date);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and this:

```
var checkPeak = function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var returnArr = new Array();
    $.each(peakStart, function(key, value) { 
        if ((date > value) && (date < value)) {
        /* december peak bookings on monday*/
            if (month != 11) {
                returnArr[0] = (day == 5);
                returnArr[1] = '';
                return returnArr;
            } else {
                returnArr[0] = (day == 1);
                returnArr[1] = '';
                return returnArr;
            }
        }
        if (month == 0) {
            returnArr[0] = false;
            return returnArr;
        } else {
            // it's not during a peak period
            returnArr[0] = (day == 1 || day == 5);
            returnArr[1] = '';
            return returnArr;
        }
    });
}
```

It worked fine for me!

Comment: Why is there no answer selected? This is a GREAT solution.

Answer (score 0):

@Penzizzle

what minimumDate u needed?? `0d` is not valid in `minDate:`

either set `minDate:'-1d'`

see [reference](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate)

Comment: Today is the minimum date - that's why I thought 0d would work!

Comment: 0d seems to work fine - I've commented out my other stuff, leaving the minDate declaration in place, and the calendars show fine.