# How to check if event dates are not overlapping an existing event

Tags: php, sql, yii, criteria, date-range

How do I check if the date ranges overlaps? I have this in my model, it keeps saving.

```
public function dateRangeExists($attribute, $params) {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id_one',$this->id_one,true,);
    $criteria->compare('id_two',$this->id_two,true,'OR');
    // $criteria->addCondition('start_date < '.$this->start_date);
    // $criteria->addCondition('end_date > '.$this->end_date);

    $criteria->addBetweenCondition('start_date', $this->start_date, $this->end_date);
    $criteria->addBetweenCondition('end_date', $this->start_date,$this->end_date);

    $record = self::model()->exists($criteria); 

    if(!empty($record)) {
         $this->addError('id', 'Item already exists within range.');
         return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you need to check first if the given `date` already exists before you're going to save an entry in your database?

Comment: how do you define overlapping?

Comment: maybe it's because of your variables type

Comment: what do you mean by overlapping? is it between the start and end date or overlapping start and end date entries?

Comment: Let's say a record of 2/1-5/31 exists. So, a new record of 1/3-4/30 is overlapped. 4/15-7/10 is also overlap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are 3 possible scenarios for event overlap:**

1. An event started before the current event (end date is after current event start date) 
   [image]
2. An event started while the current event is going on (start date is before current  event end date) 
   [image]
3. An event starts and ends during the current event (can be ignored as either rule above still applies) 
   [image]

As described above, what you need to do have a condition to check if an existing event exists where the end date is after current start date (#1), OR start date is before current end date (#2). Notice the use of the keyword `OR`:

```
WHERE (start_date < $this->start_date AND end_date > $this->start_date)
OR (start_date < $this->end_date AND end_date > $this->end_date)
```

To apply this to Yii context, I would do it this way:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addCondition(
    "WHERE (end_date > '{$this->start_date}' OR start_date < '{$this->end_date}')".
    "OR (start_date < '{$this->end_date}' AND end_date > '{$this->end_date}')"
);
```

I would also additionally use a visual calendar on the client-side to block off dates that already have an event, to avoid user selecting those dates.

If you are using jQueryUI, here's an existing solution: [jquery UI datepicker - disabling date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116121/jquery-ui-datepicker-disabling-date-ranges)